# How to serialize that class and sub class to get this XML fomat?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm currently working on the serialization stuffs. Now I'm trying to serialize a class with sub classes.

Here the skeleton of the class and sub classes I want to zerialize:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class MySubClass
    {
        public static int MySubInt { get; set; }
        public static string MySubStr { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySubClass2
    {
        public static int MySubInt2 { get; set; }
        public static string MySubStr2 { get; set; }
    }

    public static int MyInt { get; set; }
    public static string MyStr { get; set; }
}
```

NOTE: The sub classes can be enums if it seems better.

And I want to have something like:

```
<MyClass>
    <MySubClass>
        <MySubInt>42</MySubInt>
        <MySubStr>Toto</MySubStr>
    </MySubClass>
    <MySubClass2>
        <MySubInt2>4242</MySubInt2>
        <MySubStr2>Titi</MySubStr2>
    </MySubClass2>
    <MyInt>84</MyInt>
    <MyStr>Tutu</MyStr>
</MyClass>
```

I know how to serialize but I have no idea how to get something like the expected result I want to..

EDIT: I need to use this class like that:

```
int toto = MyClass.MySubClass.MySubInt;
string titi = MyClass.MyStr;
string tutu = MyClass.MySubClass2.MySubStr2;
// ...
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: These are not subclasses, they are called nested classes. They are also class definitions, which will not serialize, you must add properties exposing those classes if you want them seralized.

Comment: I don't know the name of this "pattern", sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the exact output, by exposing the nested classes as properties of the root class.

```
public class MyClass
{

    Public MySubClass MySubClass {get;set;}
    Public MySubClass2 MySubClass2 {get;set;}

    public class MySubClass
    {
        public static int MySubInt { get; set; }
        public static string MySubStr { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySubClass2
    {
        public static int MySubInt2 { get; set; }
        public static string MySubStr2 { get; set; }
    }

    public static int MyInt { get; set; }
    public static string MyStr { get; set; }
}
```

However, this is pretty bad design, and I would shy away from it.

I would also highly recommend doing some searching and read through posted articles [like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx)